# Angular Blank page - Random issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Some  of my customers, got blank page when they enter to my site.

My site based on angular application.

I try many things to restore this `"blank page"` error, for getting the console errors, but with no success.

I try open the site in different browsers.
Open multiple requests same time.
Windows / Mac.

This is my app.js file

```
    var siteApp = angular.module('siteApp', ['ui.router', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate',
'datatables','datatables.buttons','ngCookies']); 
    siteApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index");
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
      $stateProvider
          .state('app', {
              url: "/?:site_id",
              templateUrl: "/controls/angular/templates/partial/app.html",
              abstract: true
          })
          .state('app.popup', {
          }).....
    });
    siteApp.run(['$rootScope','$cookies','$state','$location','$window',
        function(
            $rootScope,$cookies, $state, $location,$window) {  
            $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                var log_route = $cookies.get("hash_route");
                if(log_route && log_route.length){   
                    var date = new Date();
                    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(-2*24*60*60*1000));
                    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
                    document.cookie = "hash_route" + "=" + undefined + "; " + expires+"; path=/";             
                    $location.url(log_route);                  
                    return null;
                }
            });  
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () { 
                try {  if (!$window.ga) {
                    } else {
                        //$window.ga('send', 'pageview', { page: $location.path() });
                    }
                } catch (x) {}
            });
        }
    ]);
```

I look for ideas for diagnose or restore this issue, or thing for debugging and getting the data error from customers.

Comment: ask for the sys/browser details from customer and preferably the error msg too

Comment: 24sharon, I'd recommend searching for "angular silent failure", and trying the suggestions in the posts on SO or elsewhere that come up. For example: http://bahmutov.calepin.co/avoiding-silent-angular-failures.html